# Vuejs dynamic component event

Tags: javascript, vue.js

there is any way to add events/triggers to a vuejs component dynamically and independent from each other?

Basically, i have a list component that will render data. I want each list component to work independent from other list components.

For example: I have a parent component that will have two lists, in which i will pass an id and will have different api methods attached, like this:

```
<list-view list-view-id="list-data-1"></list-view>
<list-view lsit-view-id="list-data-2"></list-view>
```

I want to attach two events: 'start-loading', which will show a loading view and load data from the api method, and a 'finish-loading' that will hide the loading. The parent will broadcast the finish load event when all data is available.

Problem here: if i call the $broadcast from one api method, i don't want both list-view components (children) to trigger the 'finish-load' event.

Comment: I'm a little hazy on what is supposed to do what. Can you flesh out your code into a snippet that has all the players defined?

Comment: A did another approach. This one has too many $broadcast call. basically i added one flag per list-view (needsLoading) and when i start executing the api method i set this flag to true. And when the api method returns a response a set this flag to false. For one hand i create a flag per list-view component. But in the other hand i will not have plenty of triggers. Thanks anyway :)